# "Protocol family unavailable" error while using VisualVM

Tags: visualvm

I am trying to use VisualVM to monitor my remote appliation.
I started jstatd on port 1099 in my remote box. Now when I am trying to connect I get the following error in VisualVM log file. Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated.

Thank you
Chaitanya

```
    INFO [com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.application.JvmstatApplicationProvider]: Jvmstat connection to <myserver>[IP: <my IP>] failed.
java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
Caused: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:614)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at $Proxy16.activeVms(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.rmi.RemoteVmManager.activeVms(RemoteVmManager.java:82)
    at sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.rmi.MonitoredHostProvider.activeVms(MonitoredHostProvider.java:217)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.application.JvmstatApplicationProvider.registerJvmstatConnection(JvmstatApplicationProvider.java:265)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.application.JvmstatApplicationProvider.registerJvmstatConnections(JvmstatApplicationProvider.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.application.JvmstatApplicationProvider.processNewHost(JvmstatApplicationProvider.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.application.JvmstatApplicationProvider.access$000(JvmstatApplicationProvider.java:72)
[catch] at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat.application.JvmstatApplicationProvider$1.run(JvmstatApplicationProvider.java:98)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1957)
```

Comment: For some reason IPv6 is used for connection. How exactly are you trying to connect?

Comment: I have VisualVM on my Win XP desktop trying to connect to JVM which I want to monitor on Fedora box. I started jstatd on port 1099 using the command: ./jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy -p 1099 in Fedora box and trying to connect to it from my desktop.

Comment: I got it working through JMX Connection. I chucked jstatd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has no fix. Not even by Dev team.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the jstatd port to a higher port?
I use 9099 for my jstatd because 1099 is not accessible on my intranet network.