# Node.js Selenium IPv6 Issue (SocketException Protocol family unavailable)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

This error only happens when I spawn the [ios-driver](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/) jar as a Node.js child.

The error is [`java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable`](https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver/blob/3b5d18ea6e769d30d64fb40a9a53ad1561400f68/server/src/main/java/org/uiautomation/ios/wkrdp/internal/SimulatorProtocolImpl.java#L58)

**selenium-test.js:**

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var selenium = spawn('java', ['-jar', './ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar', '-port', '4444']);
selenium.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
selenium.stderr.on('data', function (data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

**webdriverjs-test.js** ([webdriverjs](https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs))

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'safari',
        platform: 'OS X 10.9',
        version: '7.1',
        device: 'iphone'
    }
};

webdriverjs
  .remote(options)
  .init()
  .end();
```

Reproduce this error by creating the above files, running selenium-test.js in one window and webdriverjs-test.js in another window. You will first need to `npm install webdriverjs` and `curl -O http://ios-driver-ci.ebaystratus.com/userContent/ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar`

**Version info:**

```
$ java version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

$ node -v
v0.10.26
```

Why does this error happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Host about `var selenium = spawn('java', ['-jar', './ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar', '-port', '4444', '-host', '127.0.0.1']);`?

Comment: Just tried. Same issue happens.

Comment: Do you have JAVA_OPTS that has -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in your environment. That could be a reason. Also try passing them to your child process. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785854/jesey-client-on-jboss-7-1-1-throw-java-net-socketexception-protocol-family-unav)

Comment: I don't think so. I can inspect the output of `env` in my shell and in the child shell and they are almost the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this by making the spawned child ignore stdin:

`var selenium = spawn('java', ['-jar', './ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar', '-port', '4444'], {stdio: ['ignore', null, null]});`

I'm not sure why this workaround works.

Comment: Interesting. There seems to be something wrong with how OSX handles stdio. For instance I found out that an Eclipse plugin that dumps a lot of debugging output to standard out is able to crash the entire Eclipse app if it is executed from the Finder. If I start eclipse from a terminal command line, everything works.

Comment: The reason why the workaround works is not related to OSX, but instead to a bug in the JVM. See my explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573455/6395447 or the bug report in the [Java Bug Tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211842).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much idea about it, what so far I've found is that this can be  binding  issue with java. More details is on following link:(It is not the updated information, it may lead to answer)

http://diario.beerensalat.info/2008/10/12/java_and_ipv6_on_bsd.html

If that is not the case, as this post suggests to change it to higher port should work. 
["Protocol family unavailable" error while using VisualVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785852/protocol-family-unavailable-error-while-using-visualvm)

Comment: I didn't have any luck raising the port.