# IP addresses of network interfaces in a Java process spawned by NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js

A Java process which is launched by NodeJS doesn't seem to detect IPv6 addresses of network interfaces. Consider the follwing java code:

```
public class ListAddresses {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
            displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
    }

    static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) 

    throws SocketException {
            out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
            out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
            Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
            for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
                out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
            }
            out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
```

If I run it from command line, it prints the following:

```
Display name: wlan0
Name: wlan0
InetAddress: /fe80:0:0:0:6e88:14ff:fe67:8130%3
InetAddress: /192.168.1.102

Display name: lo
Name: lo
InetAddress: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
InetAddress: /127.0.0.1
```

If I launch it from within NodeJS like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var prc = spawn('java', ['ListAddresses']);

prc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('' + data);
});
```

then it's output is:

```
Display name: 
wlan0
Name: wlan0
InetAddress: /192.168.1.102

Display name: lo
Name: lo
InetAddress: /127.0.0.1
```

So the IPv6 addresses are missing. And finally, if I change the way of spawing to this:

```
var prc = spawn('java', ['ListAddresses'], { stdio: [ 'ignore', null, null] });
```

Then the launched java process prints all the IP addresses correctly (this seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22950304/594406 somehow, I don't see how, though). Does anybody have an idea what's going on? I am using java `1.8.0_66` and node `v4.2.2` on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`. Note that the parent NodeJS process detects the IPv6 addresses, and if I launch a NodeJS child then that also detects them.

Comment: Is there anything different from the question you've linked? It's the same thing I'd say: IPv6 protocol family unavailable = no network interfaces either. Looks like some strange interaction thing where the Java process somehow inherits an ipv4-only environment from node unless you detach the child process. You could try whether something non-java has the same problem

Comment: @zapl Maybe it's the same, I don't know. The parent process (NodeJS) finds the IPv6 addresses, and another NodeJS child also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a little late, but I encountered the same issue today and investigated it a little further.

This is actually not a Node.js issue, but instead some weird JVM behavior. The workaround in the original post helped me to find the root cause: If you do not pass `'ignore'` as the first entry in the `stdio` array, the subprocess will be spawned with a unix domain socket bound to file descriptor 0 (aka stdin).

The JVM has a function to detect whether IPv6 is supported or not, which among other checks includes the following [piece of code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/file/18426968f11c/src/java.base/unix/native/libnet/net_util_md.c#l307). The code does not match the description in the comment above. So the implementation actually disables IPv6 when a socket is bound to fd 0 and its type is not an IPv6 socket. So when Node.js binds a unix socket to fd 0, IPv6 gets disabled as well.

```
/*
* If fd 0 is a socket it means we've been launched from inetd or
* xinetd. If it's a socket then check the family - if it's an
* IPv4 socket then we need to disable IPv6.
*/
if (getsockname(0, &sa.sa, &sa_len) == 0) {
    if (sa.sa.sa_family != AF_INET6) {
        close(fd);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }
}
```

I reported this as a bug to the Java Bug Database, but since this code has been there for a long time it will probably not be a priority to be fixed (or maybe this is even intended?).

Update: The issue is now been confirmed to be a bug and is now visible in the [Java Bug Tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8211842).